# Passport series live input validation: NSPredicate with regex issue

Tags: ios, swift, regex, validation

I just found that regex with required number of characters doesn't work.

I used standard method with `NSPredicate` that looks like:

```
let validatedString = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", validationExpresion)
return validatedString.evaluate(with: text)
```

where `validationExpression` is my regex expression and `text` is just a string.

I tried `^[A-Z]+$` and everything works fine, but after adding range, `^[A-Z]{6}+$`, it doesn't work at all.

At the same time both expressions work well at https://regex101.com. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Note `{6}+`  = `{6}` and means *6 occurrences*.

Comment: You should add range like {0, 6} and remove +

Comment: Man, thank you so much, it works! With {0,6} without '+'. But I try to validate passport series which is XX000000 format and ^[A-Z]{0,2}?[0-9]{0,6}$ regex allows digits first, but I wanna only [A-Z]. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Is it used for live input validation? You need `^[A-Z](?:[A-Z][0-9]{0,6})?$` then.

Comment: ^[A-Z](?:[A-Z][0-9]{0,6})?$ works perfect! Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement a live input validation with a regex, you must ensure that it can match your desired format string starting with the first character, and each subsequent chars should be all optional, *but* each subsequent char should only be allowed if the preceding chars matched the  pattern.

In this case, you may use

```
^[A-Z](?:[A-Z][0-9]{0,6})?$
```

It will match strings like

```
A
AB
AB1
AB12
AB123
AB1234
AB12345
AB123456
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UZpfLx/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5BA-Z%5D(%3F%3A%5BA-Z%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B0%2C6%7D)%3F%24):

[image]

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string (not required with `MATCHES` as it requires a full string match, but can be used)
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `(?:[A-Z][0-9]{0,6})?` - an optional non-capturing group matching

  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `[0-9]{0,6}` - zero to six digits
- `$` - end  of string (not required with `MATCHES`).

Comment: The best explanation that I have ever seen before! Thanks.